# How to define color while plotting histogram using gnu

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have below code which plot the histogram of different input file. The color of the histogram changes whenever I gave a new input file.

Please let me know if there is a way such that color of the histogram is same for all the inputs file

```
    binwidth=0.00001
##Empty bins caused the box for the adjacent bin to incorrectly extend into its space
set boxwidth binwidth
set grid
bin(x,width)=width*floor(x/width) +(binwidth /2)
set title "Histogram of Instance Power"
set xlabel "Power Range in mW"
set ylabel "Instance numbers"
unset style line
set style fill solid
plot [0.0:0.0004] [1:200000] '<FILE NAME>' using (bin($2,binwidth)):(1.0) smooth freq with boxes lc variable notitle
```

Comment: Why do you use `lc variable`?

Comment: Maybe you can use `plot ... w boxes lc "your_desired_color"`. This will make histograms with all boxes having the same color.

Comment: Hi Christoph, Ptheguy

Comment: Hi Christoph, I want the bin of the histogram with different colors so I gave "ls variable". The colors of the bin should be similar as of earlier file. Example:: For First input file:: Bin 1 is RED color, Bin 2 is GREEN color and Bin 3 is BLACK color.

Comment: The Bin color should be same for other Input file having 3 bins

Comment: @NeelamGuajrathi so you have a file that you are histogramming and say you get `N` bins for it; you want each bin to have a different color? That is, `N` different colors?

Comment: 1) Yes @Ptheguy. I want different color for each bin. But the BIN color should be the same for other input file as the previous one. I see that the BIN color changes for each different <FILE NAME>.

Comment: 2) Example:: For First Input file name:::: Bin 1 is RED color, Bin 2 is GREEN color and Bin 3 is BLACK color.  FOr second input file name, I also want same color as above i.e Bin 1 is RED color, Bin 2 is GREEN color and Bin 3 is BLACK color.

Comment: 3) This is not the case as I see different bin color for second file name i.e BIN 1 is BLACK , Bin 2 is RED and Bin 3 is GREEN